# Can't click anything but chrome windows sometimes

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, window-focus

I'm running multiple windows of chrome and other programs on windows 7. Randomly chrome is the only thing I can click on that responds and there is no feedback on mouseover. Clicking on irc chat client doesn't put focus on it, clicking the taskbar doesn't open a program and clicking shortcuts on the desktop doesn't work. It's like chrome won't give up focus or thinks it's fullscreen. Crtl Alt Del stops it but it takes a few seconds for my mouse to start working on that screen. It seems to happen randomly, sometimes it's a few times a day other times it's weeks apart.